# Rename files by the third delimiter from the end of the name

Tags: powershell, rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a PowerShell code that renaming the files name, and just cutting some letters from the end of the file name. Now I am trying to rename it like this: For example my file name is "a_b_c_d_e_f.txt", so I want to change it to "a_b_c.txt". Any Ideas?

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\xxx\Projects\testfiles' -filter *.txt |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-9) + $_.Extension}
```

Comment: You actually forgot to explain what's wrong with your code.  Why are you mixing the properties `Name` and `BaseName`? What exactly do you mean with *cutting some letters from the end*? How many letters do you want to remove? What's when there are not enough letters?

Comment: Use Regex : $pattern = '^(?<keep>[a-z]_[a-z]_[a-z])(?<remove>[^.]+)(?<extension>.txt)';
$results = "a_b_c_d_e_f.txt" -replace $pattern, '${keep}${extension}';
$results

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a helper function for this:

```
function getNewName($basename, $extension){
  $s = $basename -split "_"
  $n = ($s[0..($s.Length-4)]) -join "_"
  return "$n"+$extension
}
```

Usage:

```
> new-item "a_b_c_d_e_f.txt"; 
> Get-ChildItem '.' -filter *.txt | rename-item -NewName {getNewName $_.Basename $_.Extension}

> Get-Item *.txt
a_b_c.txt
```

the logic of the helper function is to split on `_` and join all but the last three elements (in this case, `d`, `e`, and `f`).

Answer (score 2):

Use regex `-replace`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\xxx\Projects\testfiles' -Filter '*_*_*_*.txt' -File |
Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+$'), $_.Extension}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Paolo's helpful `-split` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76247641/45375) with a [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution, where the `-split` operator now accepts *negative* indices, for splitting *from the end* of a string:

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\xxx\Projects\testfiles -Filter *.txt | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    ($_.BaseName -split '_', -4)[0] + $_.Extension
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)  `'_', -4` splits the input file name into substrings by separator `_`, extracting up to 4 tokens *from the end* of the string, and returning whatever remains at the *front* of the input string as the *first* element.

  - E.g., `'a_b_c_d_e_f'` is split into prefix `'a_b_c'` and token array `@('d', 'e', 'f')` (which we're not interested in here).
- `+ $_.Extension` appends the existing extension to the resulting name, resulting in `'a_b_c.txt'`

Note:

- File names that contain *no* `_` instances are left as-is (no renaming occurs).
- File names with only 1 to 2 `_` instances are renamed to the prefix before their first `_`; e.g. `'a_b_c.txt'` becomes `'a.txt'`

  - If it's preferable not to rename such files at all, consider [Theo's helpful `-replace`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76248165/45375) or modify the `-Filter` argument to rule out names with fewer than 3 `_`
- Individual rename operations may fail, if the new, shortened names result in duplicates.